# Como implementar um LOG de atualizações com ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log, filter

Eu gostaria de ideias sobre como implementar um LOG de atualizações genérico no DB (Entity Framework 6+) que me permita descobrir informações como por exemplo: usuário do sistema X na data Y alterou nome e data de nascimento (de, para) no cadastro de clientes.

Penso que seja possível implementar algo assim de forma genérica, sem que seja necessário criar as entradas de log para cada action em cada controller, utilizando ActionFilter e/ou EntityFramework Interceptor.

Comment: Bom tem esse link: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn630210.aspx` seria a base da sua pergunta !!!

Answer (score 6):

## Passo 1. Crie um `Model` para registrar as ações

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Models 
{
    public class ActionsLog 
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ActionsLogId { get; set; }
        public String Controller { get; set; }
        public String Action { get; set; }
        public String Ip { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }
        // Coloque aqui os campos extras que deseja usar para o registro
    }
}
```

## Passo 2. Implemente um Filter derivado de `ActionFilter`

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Filters 
{
    public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Coloque aqui algumas regras de negócio que quiser antes de fazer o log.

            // Aqui é o registro propriamente dito
            var contexto = new MeuProjetoContext();

            var log = new ActionsLog()
            {
                ActionsLogId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName + " (Logged By: Custom Action Filter)",
                Ip = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress,
                DateAndTime = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
                // Coloque aqui os campos extras para inclusão
            };

            contexto.ActionsLogs.Add(log);
            contexto.SaveChanges();

            this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

## Passo 3. Registre seu `ActionFilter` no `Controller` desejado

```
[CustomActionFilter]
public class MeuController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

### Ou então decore as `Actions` individualmente

```
[CustomActionFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ...
}

[CustomActionFilter]
public ActionResult Search(string term)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: É uma boa ideia gravar em BD?

Comment: E teria como eu pegar os parametros passados por post?

Comment: Você pode gravar onde quiser. O exemplo é para log em banco, que é mais fácil. Para pegar os parâmetros por `POST`, use `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form`.

Comment: Teria algum exemplo de como utilizar o filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form?

Comment: `foreach (var campo in filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.ToList()) { ... }`