# Multitenancy com Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Eu tenho minha aplicação, que compartilha o mesmo banco de dados com todos os meus clientes.

Separando-os apenas por uma coluna da tabela `Empresa_Id`, todas minhas ações, Salvar, Listar, Editar, Excluir são feitas pelo meu repository.

No meu repository eu passo o Id da empresa, sempre antes de executar a ação. Mas no meu Editar, como ele manda o Id pela URL para retornar a View, não consigo tratar isso, e outros podem ter acesso aos dados de outros.

Então o que está falho é esse método aqui do repository:

```
public virtual T getById(int id)
{
  return _dbSet.Find(id);
}
```

Alguma ideia para contornar esse problema?

Eu pensei até em mudar minhas PK tudo para GUID, mas tenho medo que minhas consultas fiquem muito lentas (já que o Entity Framework é famoso por ser um ORM lento comparado a outros).

Comment: Tiago, então eu li já...mas é complicado sabe, eu to passando por algo bem "parecido" com o que você citou... Eu já até fiz esse modo, de retornar Null se não for da mesma "Empresa" etc...

Comment: Tiago, por curiosidade, obteve sucesso fazendo aquela condição e retornando Null no seu edit no repository ?

Comment: Perdão Tiago, confundi, o seu "Get" retornando Null quando não é da EmpresaId

Comment: Tiago, como estou usando asp.net Identity, eu deixo EmpresaId nas Claims mesmo... aí não preciso buscar do banco ou algo assim, já está em memória

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você não tem como identificar unicamente todo e qualquer registro das entidades da sua aplicação, algo está muito errado.

No modelo Multitenente, não necessariamente a chave precisa ser composta. O erro que você está tendo é por causa que a entidade foi construída mais ou menos assim:

```
public class Entidade
{
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=2)]
    public int EntidadeId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Algumas vezes já alertei pra esse tipo de abordagem. O correto seria:

```
public class Entidade
{
    [Key]
    public int EntidadeId { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Assim você pode identificar unicamente seus registros e colocar as regras de verificação de acesso na camada *Controller*, ou [através de *Filters*, conforme exemplo nessa resposta (o exemplo é pra log, mas é uma base pra um filtro de autorização)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21511/como-implementar-um-log-de-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-asp-net-mvc/21550#21550).

Agora, se **realmente** é necessário usar chave composta na aplicação, você pode alterar o link da requisição para atuar da seguinte forma:

```
http://localhost/Entidades/Edit/1?EmpresaId=2
```

O método no *Controller*, portanto, ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, int EmpresaId) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Cigano,você diz "através de filters" tem algum exemplo para isso?

Comment: Então Cigano, como eu até estava falando com o Tiago, eu não passo por parametro e sim, pego do usuário logado através das Claims, fiquei curioso quanto ao filtro, talvés não criar o filtro e sim a lógica que você tentou passar quando citou

Comment: @Rod Coloquei um link pra você.

Comment: Não, todas as minhas classes herdam de um modelBase aonde tenho apenas [Index] public int EmpresaId {get;set;}

Comment: Eu vi o erro que estava tendo, eu uso um Hidden no meu Editar para deixar o Id da entidade, e mesmo mandando um ViewModel com Id=0 ele está atribuindo o Id da URL para esse Hidden, era isso que estava me dando erro