# Posso editar minha router em tempo de execução?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho a rota da minha área

```
  context.MapRoute(
      "Cadastro_default",
      "{Empresa}/Cadastro/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { empresa = Empresa.GetEmpresa(), action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

Mas ela não executa o método GetEmpresa() durante a navegação

Comment: Você está usando errado o mecanismo de rotas. Vou responder.

Comment: Eu vi em um artigo, o cara usava algo parecido, mas não com áreas :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rota não é capaz de processar uma entidade complexa como o jeito que você está fazendo. Se bem entendi, você quer colocar o modelo multi-tenente na rota, e creio que essa abordagem seja incorreta.

O correto é você definir a empresa dentro de um Filter, [mais ou menos como faço nesta resposta, em que defino um log](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21511/como-implementar-um-log-de-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-asp-net-mvc/21550#21550).

Comment: Cigano, na verdade, era só passar o nome da empresa que está ativa na URL

Comment: @TiagoSilva Primeiro lembro se já respondi ou não. Depois dou uma pesquisada ;)